# Bio.Phylo v.1.65 on Macports does not contain TreeConstruction

Tags: macports, biopython

I am wondering why the Biopython release in Macports does not contain the Phylo.TreeConstruction module as told [here](http://biopython.org/wiki/Phylo)?

With iPython I tried :

```
In [1]: from Bio import Phylo
In [2]: Phylo.  <-- hit tab here
Phylo.BaseTree       Phylo.NexusIO        Phylo.draw_graphviz
Phylo.CDAO           Phylo.PhyloXML       Phylo.parse
Phylo.NeXML          Phylo.PhyloXMLIO     Phylo.read
Phylo.NeXMLIO        Phylo.convert        Phylo.to_networkx
Phylo.Newick         Phylo.draw           Phylo.write
Phylo.NewickIO       Phylo.draw_ascii  
In [4]: ?Phylo
Type:        module
String form: <module 'Bio.Phylo' from '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Bio/Phylo/__init__.pyc'>
File:        /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Bio/Phylo/__init__.py
Docstring:
Package for working with phylogenetic trees.

See also: http://biopython.org/wiki/Phylo
```

That's the Macports installation

I need this urgently to turn a distance matrix to a newick format for further analysis.

Thanks,
EL

Comment: How did you check that it doesn't contain it? If you did it by trying to import it in a Python interpreter and it failed, are you sure you used MacPorts Python? The Portfile doesn't do anything special, so you should end up with a standard installation as defined by upstream.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's there, but for some reason it doesn't show up in `dir(Bio.Phylo)` and is thus not completed automatically by IPython.

Try:

```
/opt/local/bin/python2.7 -c 'from Bio.Phylo.TreeConstruction import _Matrix'
```

That's not something MacPorts did -- it seems this is either a deliberate or accidental decision made upstream. You should file a bug and request that these packages are properly exported.